# SQLDelight multiplatform not generating schema if it is in a separate module

Tags: kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

I have modularized my shared code, so currently I have a `shared` module (kmp), and inside this module I have `shared:core` and `shared:database` (both multiplatform too).
If I set up the database in the shared module it works: I place my AppDatabase.sq in the commonMain folder in shared, in sqldelight/com/example/kmmbase/database/ and the schema is correctly generated.
On the other hand, if I try to move it to the `shared:database` module it does not generate the schema, and the driver won't compile. I add the AppDatabase.sq file to the same path but now in the commonMain of the `shared:database` module, and I move the sqldelight plugin and gradle config from the `shared` gradle file to the `shared:database` gradle file.
The gradle config I have is as follows:

```
sqldelight {
    database("AppDatabase") {
        packageName = "com.example.kmmbase.database"
        sourceFolders = listOf("sqldelight")
    }
}
```

I've tried different locations for the .sq file, and on each one I match the gradle config's packageName:

- sqldelight/com/example/kmmbase/shared/
- sqldelight/com/example/kmmbase/database/
- sqldelight/com/example/database/
- sqldelight/com/example/database/database/
- sqldelight/database/
- ...

Any idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Edit: here's [a repo](https://github.com/jsaumellbasetis/TestSqlDelight) with the code.

Comment: I think we'll really need to see the configs in full.

Comment: If edited the question adding a repository with the project @KevinGalligan

Comment: I'll take a look, although ping me again if you don't hear anything back after the weekend...

Comment: I'm stuck just opening the project https://gist.github.com/kpgalligan/5e01aa9aad45b1c44a2d7e1a55726820

Comment: Thank you for helping with this @KevinGalligan
I forgot to mention that I use Android Studio Canary 9. In newer versions it does not work (I have to adapt it). And in older versions it probably does not work either. Is it possible that it is because of this that it won't open?

Comment: I have pushed a branch "newer_as" that works with canary 14 in case that's better for you (disabling some compiler options that I'm not sure if they will be needed).
I can try removing compose entirely if thats what doesn't let you open the project

Comment: Hi @KevinGalligan have you been able to look into this?

Comment: It's still failing.
```An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'com.android.application']
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
     You can try some of the following options:
       - changing the IDE settings.
       - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
       - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.```

Comment: Sorry about the bad formatting :) I'm not sure why, but I don't want to try to debug the project config. It's saying I'm on Java 1.8 but I'm running 11. Canary 14.

Comment: have you tried building the database? `gradlew ./build`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*tldr;*

According to your current repository structure, you have the `sqldelight` directory inside `src/commonMain/kotlin`. It should however be on the same level with `kotlin`, in your situation `/shared/database/src/commonMain/sqldelight`.

*Full answer*

Each gradle module has it's own `build.gradle.kts` file. The one that loads the plugin `com.squareup.sqldelight` is also the one that will look into the according source files. With that said, if you want your `.sq` files to be in your `:shared:database` module, you have to check the following parts:

1. the `sqldelight` plugin is included in `/shared/database/build.gradle.kts`
2. The `sqldelight` is configured in `/shared/database/build.gradle.kts`
3. Inside the configuration of `sqldelight` there is the option to override the default source folder which is `sqldelight` with the `sourceFolders` attribute. By default and with he above configuration it is `/shared/database/src/commonMain/sqldelight`
4. Inside the configured source folder, you have to use the package structure defined in the configuration (like with packageName `com.example` you would have the directory `/shared/database/src/commonMain/sqldelight/com/example/MySQLFile.sq` (not very sure about this step though)